# Maximum number of common normal of $y^2=4ax$ and $x^2 = 4by$

Tags: analytic-geometry

> Maximum number of common normal of $y^2=4ax$ and $x^2 = 4by$

Attempt: Equation of normal to the curve $y^2=4ax$ in slope form $y=mx-2am-am^3.$

Now above equation is also normal to $x^2=4by$

I could not understand how to solve further, thanks.

Comment: eq of normal for parabola of form $x^2=4by$ is $y=mx+2b + \frac{b}{m^2}$.Compare the 2 equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a normal to $y^2=4ax$ has the form

$$tx+y-2at-at^3=0$$

and a normal to $x^2=4by$ has the form

$$x+sy-2bs-bs^3=0$$

A common normal of the two parabolae has its equation expressible in both the above two forms. Obviously, $s\ne0$ and $t\ne0$.

The second equation can be written as

$$tx+sty-2bst-bs^3t=0$$

Therefore, $st=1$ and

\begin{align*}
-2at-at^3&=-2bst-bs^3t\\
&=-2b-bs^2\\
&=-2b-\frac{b}{t^2}\\
2at^3+at^5&=2bt^2+b
\end{align*}

Let $f(t)=at^5+2at^3-2bt^2-b$. Then $f(-t)=-at^5-2at^3-2bt^2-b$.

If $a$ and $b$ are of the same sign, then the coefficients of $f(t)$ has one sign change and the coefficients of $f(-t)$ has no sign change. So $f(t)$ has one positive root and no negative root.

If $a$ and $b$ are of opposite signs, then the coefficients of $f(t)$ has no sign change and the coefficients of $f(-t)$ has one sign change. So $f(t)$ has no positive root and one negative root.

Therefore, $f(t)$ has only one real root. The two parabolae have at most one common normal.

Comment: What is the meaning of "one sign change"? Please explain.

Comment: From $2a$ to $2b$, there is one sign change.

Comment: You mean to from $2at^3$ to $2bt^2$?

Comment: Yes. For the case of same sign

Comment: Again one more doubt! How did you about the roots from that sign change? Is there any method which should be known to me?

Comment: How did you conclude from sign change about the roots nature?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs